# How to add two dictionary object with __add__?

Tags: python, dictionary, object, addition

For example I have two objects:

> Ex(['d', 'c', 'd', 'a'])
>
> Ex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'b', 'a'])

These objects will produce dictionary of:

> {'d':2, 'c':1, 'a':1}
>
> {'a':2, 'b':2, 'c':1, 'x':1}

How can I add these two dict objects to produce result like this?:

> Ex(a[2],b[2],c[2],d[2],x[1])

Neither of Ex operand should be changed.

So I came up with code below:

```
def __add__(self, another):
    r = self._val.copy()
    for key, val in another._val.items():
        if key in r:
            r[key] += val
        else:
            r[key] = val
    return r
```

But this seems not working properly, and getting error on automated checker I have to go through.

I do have to use dunder add, and both Ex objects cannot be changed.

Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Comment: Can you please expand your code example in the question to be a [mcve]?

Comment: I think the result must be `Ex(a[3]...)` (1+2)

Answer (score 1):

Use Counter to do things like this, and remember **Composition Over Inheritance** (or composite reuse principle), so your Ex class dunder add should look like this when using counter:

```
from collections import Counter


class Ex:
    def __init__(self, characters):
        self.counter = Counter(characters)

    def get_result(self):
        return dict(self.counter.items())

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Ex):
            return NotImplemented
        result = Ex([])
        result.counter = self.counter + other.counter
        return result


ex_1 = Ex(['d', 'c', 'd', 'a'])
ex_2 = Ex(['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'b', 'a'])
ex_3 = ex_1 + ex_2

print(ex_1.get_result())  # {'d': 2, 'c': 1, 'a': 1}
print(ex_2.get_result())  # {'a': 2, 'b': 2, 'c': 1, 'x': 1}
print(ex_3.get_result())  # {'d': 2, 'c': 2, 'a': 3, 'b': 2, 'x': 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you objective is to add two dictionaries then you can use 'update'
Ex dict1={'a':1,'b':2} and dict2 ={'a':2,'c':3} then dict1.update(dict2) will update the values of dict2 into dict1. When you print dict1 it will output {'a':2,'b':2,'c':3}